# Error: Not a graph object in R shiny

Tags: r, csv, shiny, igraph

Does anyone how to fix this error when I'm trying to find the degree of each vertex from the input file? [Here's](https://www.dropbox.com/s/got76j05yygmxka/network.net?dl=0) the Pajek file i want to import in and export the degree into CSV.

When I tried using a smaller input file. The renderTable works but when I tried with my file(which is in the link) it somehow keeps showing that error message and does not display on the tab set.

Here's what I've done so far:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Finding most influential vertex in a network"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      fileInput("graph", label = h4("Pajek file")),

      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')

    ),
    mainPanel( tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                           tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("view")) 

                           ) 

               )                        
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(igraph)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=-1) 

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    filedata <- reactive({
      inFile = input$graph
      if (!is.null(inFile))
      read.graph(file=inFile$datapath, format="pajek")

    })

    Data <- reactive({

      df <- filedata()
      vorder <-order(degree(df), decreasing=TRUE)
      DF <- data.frame(ID=as.numeric(V(df)[vorder]), degree=degree(df)[vorder])

    })
    output$view <- renderTable({

      Data()

    })

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

      filename = function() {
        paste("degree", '.csv', sep='')
      },


      content = function(file) {

      write.csv(Data(), file)
      } 

    )


    })
```

Also, I'm also not sure how to write to csv file from the data frame I've output.

Comment: To write to csv, [this example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html) shows you need to call the (reactive) function that creates the data, i.e. `write.csv(reactive_df(), file)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the data that's being created is in the overview$view <- renderTable specificly the "DF" statement. How do i retrieve from that statement? @tospig

Comment: I would create the DF in a reactive expression, `DF <- reactive({ df <- filedata() ... etc...})` , then you can call `DF()` inside both the `write.csv` and `renderTable` functions

Comment: That's a great idea. But is there something wrong with my function() in downloadHandler. Because after i tried your method, it doesn't really create a csv file? @tospig

Comment: It *looks* right - how are you running the app, through RStudio? If so, try 'opening it in browser' as I've had issues in the past 'downloading' direct from RStudio's Shiny browser.

Comment: The app will prompt the user to select a Pajek file and then it will calculate the degree and show it on the "view" tab set. After showing the data frame, It will allow the user to download the data frame to a csv file. @tospig

Comment: It works perfectly in browser, thank you! But do you know why it export to csv file name like : "network.net.csv"? how do i remove the ".net" extension when saving to csv file? @tospig

Comment: You're unsing `input$graph` as the first part of the file name; change this to what you want.

Comment: I did change to a name example "degree" but then it shows error saying "degree not found in file name" when I click download.. @tospig

Comment: In quotes - `"degree"` ?

Comment: Thanks it works! But do you know how to save the output file in the same folder location where the user were prompt to input file? @tospig